# What is wrong with my sscanf format

Tags: c, string, buffer, cgi

I'm trying to deal with form data in c here.

```
fgets(somedata, bufferone, stdin);
```

if I printf 'somedata', I get:

```
username=John&password=hispass123
```

now when I try to sscanf using

```
char usr[100], pass[100];
sscanf(somedata, "username=%s&password=%s", usr, pass);
printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
printf("%s is value 1\n", usr);
printf("%s is value 2\n", pass);
```

than I get

```
John&password=hispass123 is value 1
?? is value 2
```

I suspect, the first call reads up to the null-terminator, and then second call overflows or something.

So I need help with the format. Also, is sscanf function the best choice in this scenario? I'm trying to obtain 2 strings from the message body (sent via stdin by the html form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"%s"` is greedy. It picks up everything in its path that is not a whitespace character. Change it to use `"%[^&]"`.

```
sscanf(somedata, "username=%[^&]&password=%s", usr, pass);
```

The `%[^&]` part of the format specifier will extract any character that is *not* the character `&`. It will stop extracting when it encounters a `&`.

To make your code a bit more robust, always check the return value of `sscanf/fscanf`.

```
int n = sscanf(somedata, "username=%[^&]&password=%s", usr, pass);
if ( n != 2 )
{
   // There was a problem reading the data.
}
else
{
   // Reading was successful. Use the data.
   printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
   printf("%s is value 1\n", usr);
   printf("%s is value 2\n", pass);
}
```

Comment: can you explain/elaborate a bit, how n!=2 logic works here, as well as how [^&] works. Also, I would be grateful, if you can provide a alternative to the approach I have taken so far.

Comment: @AhmadBilal, `sscanf/fscanf` return the number of receiving arguments successfully assigned. In your case, when reading of `usr` and `pass` is successful, the return value will be 2. Regarding how the format specifier works, I recommend reading [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). It doesn't make sense for me to repeat the information.

Comment: Use of `sscanf` is fine for what you have presented in your code. If you expect the input to be more complex or you have to account for input that cannot be processed by the above format specifier, then you have to use a different approach. What that approach would look like depends on the kinds of input you would like to be able to process. I think it's too broad to address in the context of your original post.

Comment: What you said about n!=2 is helpful, I have no more doubts on that. And about alternate methods is reasonable, so I will not ask more of you. But regarding the format specifier, I did look at the documentation, but was not able to make sense of it. I think you are referring to [set] modifier? Can you just put it in few simple words. btw, was I right in thinking that %s modifier read upto the end of the string instead of until '&' as I intended?

Comment: @AhmadBilal, I updated the answer a bit. Hopefully that is what you are looking for. And, yes to the last statement.

Comment: Yes, Thank you.